# How to convert markdown notation to html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I have markdown like this

```
[API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) can be accessed on [http://localhost:3000/api/hello](http://localhost:3000/api/hello). This endpoint can be edited
```

How can I convert something like this to

```
<p><a href="https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction">API routes</a>. can be accessed on 
<a href="http://localhost:3000/api/hello">http://localhost:3000/api/hello</a></p>
```

I am trying to implement this on ReactJS .

Comment: simplest way is to climb onto the shoulders of giants and look for a library that does it for you - the harder way is to start writing some code - either way, as it stands, the question won't be answered

Comment: http://showdownjs.com/ first result on google. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: `var html = \`<p>${md.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>')}</p>\`;` (md is the markdown)

Comment: Do you just need to convert this specific md to html, or do you need to convert md into html in general?